# Interface method missing from base class... COM?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4, envdte

I'm working with Microsoft's [EnvDTE Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte100.solution4?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and I noticed the methods/properties unique to the newest Interfaces aren't included in the base type. For example, the [AddFromTemplateEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte100.solution4.addfromtemplateex?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE100_Solution4_AddFromTemplateEx_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_UInt32_) method.

```
DTE dte = (DTE) ((IServiceProvider) Host).GetCOMService(typeof(DTE));
Solution4 solution = (Solution4)dte.Solution; //Solution4 is an interface
WriteLine(solution.GetType().FullName);
```

The above code writes out:

```
EnvDTE.SolutionClass
```

Yet the [EnvDTE.SolutionClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionclass?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) does not contain an implementation for AddFromTemplateEx(). I'm confused because I can still use the methods from the Solution4 interface, but I don't see how if they aren't implemented in the SolutionClass.

What magic is happening here? The SolutionClass is MarshaledbyRef, its base type is System._ComObject... Is this something to do with the Interface implementations existing on the underlying COM object and not the base type?

Comment: It would be better if Microsoft did not document these XxxxClass types.  But they are a bit too obvious in a c# or vb.net project, so they kinda have to.  They are "fake" classes, auto-generated by the type library importer.  A COM coclass does not expose its implementation at all, it only lists what interfaces it implements.  One is special, the default interface, Xxxx.  The fake class merges the members of all the interfaces.  A consequence of auto-generating it is that the fake class looks different in different VS versions.  And that the docs can't keep up.

Comment: Thanks so much! What do you mean by XxxxClass type?

Comment: Xxxx == Solution in your question.  It is the default interface, goes back to 2002.  The actual class that implements it is written in C++, not visible at all.  Today it also implements the Solution2, Solution3 and Solution4 interfaces.  New features getting added over the years.

Comment: Hmm thank you lots to think about. You could move this to answer if you like :)

Comment: ahh but one last question... if the importer is creating the COM coclass, how come the cast to (Solution4) on the SolutionClass object is not failing? I'm looking at the decompiled code and I don't see the Solution4 interface being implemented anywhere on SolutionClass or its implemented interfaces

Comment: Just more of the way COM is special.  They made the syntax look familiar to C# programmers.  What *really* happens is that the CLR calls [IUnknown.QueryInterface()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78xw8kzk.aspx).  The actual C++ class object you created, more up to date than the SolutionClass wrapper you are looking at, knows about it so is happy to return the interface pointer.  This interface-based programming paradigm is core to the way Microsoft writes its code.  Follow the links at the bottom of the linked article to learn more about it.

Comment: Perfect thanks, really appreciate it